# Hadoop Job Doesn't Get Killed

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, jobs

I'm trying to kill my Hadoop job. I run the command hadoop job -kill . 
It responds with Killed job

For some reason the job doesn't get killed and it still shows up on the job list.

How do I fix this? Any suggestions? I've googled and came up with dead ends.

Comment: Experiencing this same problem which is insanely frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Try `hadoop job -kill <job_id>` multiple times. It works for me.